# Converting string timestamp to datetime using pyarrow

Tags: python, pyarrow

Is there any possibility to convert string timestamp in pyarrow table to datetime format before writing to parquet file?

Comment: is arrow library same as pyarrow library?

Comment: I think the arrow (http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a generic library for date, time manipulation, but I am talking about pyarrow(https://arrow.apache.org/install/). I have already had my data in pyarrow table. I want to convert a column which has a string timestamp format. What I am looking is how can I read a specific column in the table and do type conversion.

Comment: Can you not just use pythons .format() function?

Comment: Could you please add some examples? What you are getting in input and what do you want to get at the output?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the timestamp format, you can make use of [`pyarrow.compute.strptime`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.strptime.html) function. It is not well-documented yet, but you can use something like this:

```
import pyarrow.compute as pc
pc.strptime(table.column("Timestamp"), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', unit='s')
```

provided your data is stored in `table` and `"Timestamp"` is the name of the column with timestamp strings.

Comment: Will this modify the column inplace? Or do you need to assign the result back to `table.column("Timestamp")` or `table['Timetamp']`?

Comment: No, it won't make an inplace change.